# Xamarin Forms: How to add single and double tap for an image?

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, gesture-recognition

I am trying to implement a keypad UI. In the keypad, the **+(plus)** and **0(zero)** options are placed on a single image icon. So I need to show **0** on UI for single tap and for double tap I need to show the **+** on UI.

**My Code**

```
<Image 
    Grid.Column="1"
    Source="ic_zero_xx.png"
    Style="{StaticResource KeypadImageStyle}">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="ZeroTapped"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
        </TapGestureRecognizer>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

private void ZeroTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    phonenumber_label.Text = "0";
}
```

[image]

**How I can mention 2 different taps at the same time on an image?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add two `TapGestureRecognizer` on that image, one for single tap and  the other for double tap .

#### xaml

```
 <Image >
     <Image.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Single" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Double" NumberOfTapsRequired="2"/>
     </Image.GestureRecognizers>
 </Image>
```

#### Code behind

```
  private void TapGestureRecognizer_Single(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      label.Text = "0";
  }

  private void TapGestureRecognizer_Double(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      label.Text = "+";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a timer If user tap twice within 150ms then it is a double tap.

```
int Tapped=0;
private void ZeroTapped(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if(Tapped==0)
    {
        Device.StartTime(TimeSpan.FromMillSeconds(150),()=>
        {
            if(Tapped=1)
            {
                //1 tap.
            }
            else
            {
                 //double tap.
            }
            Tapped=0;

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Tapped++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I am missing on this?

Comment: @SreejithSree sorry I have forgot some codes update it now.